# Brownie compile ValueError: Invalid NPM block with OpenZeppelin

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, openzeppelin, brownie, erc721

*****top lines of my .sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract ParcelAsset is ERC721 {

******command line VScode
brownie compile contracts\ParcelAsset.sol

I get this error.
ValueError: Invalid NPM block in '>=0.6.0 <0.8.0 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol"': 'import'

*********** snippet of my brownie-config.yaml
dependencies:

- smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
- OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  compiler:
  solc:
  remappings:

  - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
  - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'

I have tried
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
and upadating solidity to 0.8.0

Anyone known what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing: npm install @chainlink/contracts --save

and in the yaml file doing:[image]

I personally didn't bother importing openzeppelin because all safemath functionalities (if that is what you are importing) are already implemented into solidity 0.8.0, so if you're using solidity 0.8.0, the safemath library is obsolete